# Matlab boxplot for multiple fields

Tags: matlab, multiple-databases, boxplot

I have this matlab file which has a field called "data". In "data" I have lots of fields for different bonds (x5Q12... etc).
[image]

I am trying to produce ONE box plot that contains ONE column from each of the fields (i.e. a box diagram with 36 boxes in it). I tried this code (e.g. to plot a box for column 2 in all of the bonds) but it does't work for me:

```
boxplot(gilts_withoutdates.data.:(:,2));figure(gcf);
```

I know my understanding of calling different levels in a structure is a problem here. Any suggestions, please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [STRUCTFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/structfun.html) to extract the data from a particular column of all fields of a structure.

```
col2plot = 2; %# this is the column you want to plot

%# return, for each field in the structure, the specified
%# column in a cell array
data2plot = structfun(@(x){x(:,col2plot)},gilts_withoutdates.data);

%# convert the cell array into a vector plus group indices
groupIdx = arrayfun(@(x)x*ones(size(data2plot{x})),1:length(data2plot),'uni',0);
groupIdx = cat(1,groupIdx{:});
data2plot = cat(1,data2plot{:});

%# create a compact boxplot
boxplot(data2plot,groupIdx,'plotStyle','compact','labels',labels)
```

If you're interested in the distribution of the data, I can recommend my function [distributionPlot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23661-violin-plots-for-plotting-multiple-distributions-distributionplot-m).

Comment: Hi Jonas the code pulls out the data really well and places it in a cell 36x1. But when I try to plot using the boxplot command I receive the following error: "??? Error using ==> boxplot>straightenX at 947
'X' parameter must be a numeric vector or matrix.

Error in ==> boxplot at 273
[xDat,gDat,origRow,xlen,gexplicit,origInd,origNumXCols] = straightenX(x,g);

Error in ==> boxplotfunction at 8
boxplot(data2plot,'plotStyle','compact') " I have tried to work out whats causing it but have not been successful. As an aside: will the field name be under each box to distinguish them?

Comment: @Mary: Your code fails because there are arrays that contain only NaNs. I added a line to remove bad data, and to plot field names with the boxplot.

Comment: Unfortunately the error persists... I've tried again to swap things round to avoid it, but with no luck. There are some columns with only NaN but even when I choose column 1 or 2 (where they are populated with values) I still get the error.

Comment: @Mary: Wow, I didn't expect `boxplot` to choke on NaNs (I haven't been using it for a while now since I use `distributionPlot` almost exclusively). Anyway, here you go.

Comment: Still doesn't work. If I use the code you had before the last one and use distributionPlot(data2plot,'histOpt',2) I get a figure but without the the field names. I'm sorry to come back to you about it... I don't mind using distributionPlot if it is more stable my priority is to get it into a diagram but my matlab knowledge is v.limited.

Comment: @Mary: turns out the error was all mine. Should be fixed for good. Also, use the `xnames` option in `distributionPlot` for adding labels, and `rotateticklabel` from the File Exchange to rotate labels if needed.

Comment: Wonderful! works great once I add the labels=.. bit. Having looked at distributionPlot (and liking it) if you can give me the alternative command (so far I can only get the first box to change) that would be great? If not, don't worry. I really appreciate your time on this! Many many thanks!

Comment: @Mary: `distributionPlot(data2plot,'groups',groupIdx,'xNames',labels)`

Comment: Perfect. A little better than box plot I think! Much obliged. Really appreciate all you've done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
B=gilts_withoutdates.data;
b=fieldnames(B);
for a=1:numel(b)
  boxplot(B.(b{a})); fig;
end
```

To plot a boxplot for each of the 5 columns of data for each field you could do this:

```
   pos=1;
   for i = 1:numel(b)
    for ii=1:5
       subplot(numel(b),5,pos);boxplot(B.(b{i})(:,ii));pos=pos+1;
    end
   end
```

Comment: To accomplish what you were trying to do in your post, i.e. produce a boxplot for column two of each fieldname, replace the above with:  `boxplot(B.(b{a})(:,2));fig;`

Comment: Hi AGS. Thanks for this. It cycles through all the plots (single box plot for each 'a') and leaves me with the last one only. How do I get all the boxes to be in a single figure? Thanks again.

Comment: It should make `b` number of plots.  Are they all stacked on top of each other?  Anyway, to make a single figure (which might look too overloaded with that many boxplots) change the command in the loop to `subplot(numel(b),1,i);boxplot(B.(b{i}));`.  This plots the five boxplots for each field in a row.

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to plot each boxplot using `subplot`.

Comment: yes they are all stacked and too small to even work out that they are even figures! I do not think subplot is the answer as it will probably squash them altogether and as they are all separate graphs there is a lot of redundant space. I think that box plot itself should plot each time series on the same figure. Maybe the answer is to extract the relevant columns from each field and place them in a temporary single file before boxplot is called? I don't know.

Comment: What you are asking for is what I originally suggested, I think.  Why not plot each of the 5 columns on one plot ( one plot per field) and save each one?

Comment: the output is not usable, unfortunately. The problem is that I will need to do this for many data sets and having it generate one box plot containing the column I choose for all the fields in the dataset would save me a lot of time. Plus a single plot as opposed to a combined subplot of lots of plots would also save a lot of space.